# Angular change detection SignalR breaks upon disconnect

Tags: angular, signalr

I'm trying to get SignalR to reconnect correctly after any kind of connection error or otherwise. I have this working. However, once an error has happened, the Angular change detection breaks. SignalR still receives the events, but I have to do any kind of UI interaction (like switching a toggle that doesn't do anything, or pressing any button) to get the UI to update.

I am presuming that the issue lies in error handling, but I'd greatly appreciate some pointers on what the actual issue can be as it is not clear to me how to do this and I can't find any good examples. The scenario I'm testing is simply stopping the IIS service, after which the SignalR connection fails immediately with errors visible in the console. Then when I start it again it reconnects, but the change detection is now broken.

I'm currently using version 7.0.0 of the Microsoft/SignalR client package in Angular 15.

Additional information: it seems like with 6.0.11 I only have this in production branches.